# Ejecutar Metodo durante un periodo de Tiempo

Tags: android, android-studio

Mi objetivo es que dado un tiempo por el usuario, en ese tiempo el teléfono vibre para todas las llamadas. Esto ultimo lo se hacer, lo que no se como hacer es que se ejecute durante determinado periodo de tiempo, por ejemplo de las 6:00am-11:00am, luego a las 11:01am deje de vibrar o sea no se ejecute mas el metodo...GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO

Comment: Hola Andry has intentado alguna forma? agrega tu código

Comment: No, espero que me den ideas, NO QUE ME PONGAN EL CÓDIGO DE COMO SERIA, pero si que me digan que buscar, por donde empesar..

Comment: Si quieres opiniones tal vez tu pregunta sea cerrada :(, regularmente la comunidad busca ayudar a partir de una investigación o código que se trato previamente, te sugiero revisar [ask] para más detalles.

Comment: Te sugiero revises la clase AlarmManager, y vuelvas a preguntar algo más especifico, en el sitio se encuentra información: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+alarmmanager